# Solr Query not found

Tags: solr

I have a solr-MSSQL server settng annd I import data from sql data base and all my data is on-uicode. the import is done very well but when searching, it failes to bring the result although when I query *.* it returns some results. is there any suggestion why it is so?

Comment: You'll have to provide more context, things like: your schema (the field definitions), example data, what your query looks like, which query handler you're using, and what you're searching for -- what result you get back, and what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you searching the data ? whats the query ? can you post the queries and the configuration ?

To start with : -

`q=*:*` searches for all content on all the documents, hence you get back the results.

`q=something` will search for something on the default search field, which is usually text if you have not modified the schema.xml.

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

You can change the default field to be the field you want to search on.
OR use specific field to search on the specific field e.g. title `q=some_field:something`

If you want to search on multiple field, you can combine the fields into one field by using copyfields or use [dismax request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin).